# css issue in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

I am using a WordPress plugin and it has collapse arrows in the  option.

However, by default the word press theme has bluestar(*) being used for ul.

In the page http://everything-evans.com/, on the sidebar, under the title 'In the past', I want to display the collapsing arrows, and the star and yellow dots should disappear.

Let me know how to achieve this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You may replace the used image (/wp-content/themes/calendar-new-york/images/arrow1.png).

Or you edit your stylesheet of the selected theme (/wp-content/themes/calendar-new-york/style.css). At #sidebar1 ul ul li {} theres an background-image specified which may be replaced or deleted.

BTW: The correct CSS implementation would be "list-style-image" instead of "background-image", refer to [SitePoint CSS Reference](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/list-style-image)

Comment: some people use the background image to keep the list dot in a specific position with multiple lines of text in an <li>